# Referencing to the next index in iterrows()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame which looks like this:

```
       top         heading  page_no
0   000000           Intro        0
1   100164         Summary        1
2   100451      Experience        1
3   200131          Awards        2
4   200287         Skills         2
5   300147       Education        3
6   300273          Awards        3
7   300329       Interests        3
8   300434  Certifications        3
9   401135             End        4
```

I have used a filter which uses this dataframe to get the contents from another dataframe. It needs to filter everything between the tops i.e. from 000000 to 100164 and so on till 300434 to 401135.

```
for index,row in df_heads.iterrows():
    begin = int(row['top'])
    end = ???
    filter_result = result['data'][(result.top < end) & (result.top > begin)]
    print(row['heading'])
    print(filter_result)
    sections[row['heading']] = filter_result
    end = begin
```

What should **end** be initialized with so that we get the contents of the filter in the correct way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can create new column by [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) and then replace last `NaN` to `0` if necessary by `fillna`:

```
df_heads['shifted_top'] = df_heads['top'].shift(-1).fillna(0)
print (df_heads)
      top         heading  page_no  shifted_top
0       0           Intro        0     100164.0
1  100164         Summary        1     100451.0
2  100451      Experience        1     200131.0
3  200131          Awards        2     200287.0
4  200287          Skills        2     300147.0
5  300147       Education        3     300273.0
6  300273          Awards        3     300329.0
7  300329       Interests        3     300434.0
8  300434  Certifications        3     401135.0
9  401135             End        4          0.0

for index,row in df_heads.iterrows():
    begin = int(row['top'])
    end =  int(row['shifted_top'])
    print (begin, end)

0 100164
100164 100451
100451 200131
200131 200287
200287 300147
300147 300273
300273 300329
300329 300434
300434 401135
401135 0
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot access a different row's data using a for index, row in df_heads.iterrows() loop.  There needs to be an additional variable create outside of the loop with the different row's data as in the example from above.

```
df_heads['shifted_top'] = df_heads['top'].shift(-1).fillna(0)
```